# Validate negative to positive ranged number Joi

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I am trying to validate latitude and longitude though Joi.
Allowed latitude number range is `-90 to +90`
Allowed longitude number range is `-180 to +180`

```
const schema = Joi.object({
    map_lat: Joi.number()
      .min(-90)
      .max(90)
      .messages({ 'number.base': "Invalid latitude!" }),
    map_lng: Joi.number()
      .min(-180)
      .max(180)
      .messages({ 'number.base': "Invalid longitude!" }),
  })
```

I am getting below error.

> Error: limit must be a positive integer or reference

I also tried :

```
map_lng: Joi.number()
    .positive()
    .negative()
    .min(-90)
    .max(90)
```

But still getting same error.
Anyone can help *How can I validate -ve to +ve ranged values?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way there is `greater()` and `less()` for numbers in the doc [here](https://hapi.dev/family/joi/api/?v=17.1.0#numberlesslimit)

```
const schema = Joi.object({
    map_lat: Joi.number()
      .greater(-90)
      .less(90)
      .messages({ 'number.base': "Invalid latitude!" }),
    map_lng: Joi.number()
      .greater(-180)
      .less(180)
      .messages({ 'number.base': "Invalid longitude!" }),
  })
```

Comment: I know this post is a little old, but surely `.greater(-90)` will reject a value of exactly -90 and `.less(90)` will reject exactly 90. `.min(-90).max(90)` would be more correct.